# Refresh page after submit form in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, components, submit, refresh

When I change the price of my program in the input and I click on the update button, all is well the price changes but when I refresh my page I have an error that appears and even when I do not modify the price and I just refresh the page this error appears and I don't understand why

Here is the screenshot of the error and you will find my code below
[image]

App

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './css/App.css';
import './css/Products.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import Navigation from './Components/Navigation';
import Products from './Components/Products';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch,} from 'react-router-dom';
import ProductsDetails from './Components/ProductsDetails';

export default function App() {
 
  const [productsData, setProductsData] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://fakestoreapi.com/products?limit=7").then((res) => {
      setProductsData(res.data);
    });
  }, []);
  const updatePrice = (id, price) => {
    setProductsData((productsData) => 
      productsData.map((product) =>
        product.id === Number(id)
          ? {
              ...product,
              price: Number(price)
            }
          : product
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Navigation/>
        <Switch>        
          <Route 
            path="/products-details/:id"
            render={(props) => (
              <ProductsDetails 
                products={productsData}
                updatePrice={updatePrice}
                {...props}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Route path="/"> 
            <Products products={productsData}
            /> 
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Products

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../css/Products.css';
import './ProductsDetails'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

export default class Products extends Component {
  render() {
    const listsProducts = this.props.products.map((listProduct) => {
      return (
        <tbody className="products__body" key={listProduct.id}>
          <tr>
          <td><Link to={{pathname: "/products-details/" + listProduct.id}}>{listProduct.title}</Link></td>
            <td><p className={`${listProduct.category==="men's clothing" ? "category__orange" : "category__green"}`}>{listProduct.category}</p></td>
            <td>{Number(listProduct.price).toFixed(2)}</td>
            <td>
              {Number(listProduct.price * 1.2).toFixed(2)} €
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      );
    });
    return (
      <main className="products">
        <h1 className="products__title">Products management</h1>
        <table cellSpacing="0">
          <thead className="products__head">
            <tr>
              <th className="table--title">Product name</th>
              <th className="table--title">Category</th>
              <th className="table--title">Price</th>
              <th className="table--title">Price (including VAT)</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          {listsProducts}
        </table>
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

ProductsDetails

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import '../css/ProductsDetails.css'
import {AiOutlineArrowLeft} from "react-icons/ai";
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'


export default class ProductsDetails extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      // ajout de deux états l'id qu'on récupére de l'API et le prix qui vaut 0
      this.state = { 
          id: this.props.match.params.id, 
          price: 0
        };
    }
    
    // mise en place d'une méthode qui permet de modifier la valeur dans l'input texte 
    updatePrice = (e) => {
      console.log(e);
      this.setState({
        price: e.target.value
      });
    };
    
    /*
    mise en place d'une méthode qui permet au clique du bouton de changer le prix 
    grâce à la méthode "updatePrice ainsi que l'id et l'état du prix du produit
    */
    submitHandler = (e) => {
        // permet au clique du bouton que concerver localement la valeur modifiée 
        localStorage.setItem('price', this.state.price)
      e.preventDefault();
      const {
        match: {
          params: { id }
        }
      } = this.props;
      this.props.updatePrice(id, this.state.price);
      
    };

    // permet de garder la valeur modifiée au refresh de la page 
    componentDidMount() {
        const price = localStorage.getItem('price')
        this.setState({price});
    }
  
    render() {
      const {
        match: {
          params: { id }
        },
        products
      } = this.props;
      
      // Ajout d'une variable qui récupére le premier id trouvé dans le tableau "products"
      const listProduct = products.find((product) => product.id === Number(id));
  
      return (
        <div className="products__details">
          <Link to="/">
            <AiOutlineArrowLeft className="nav__arrow" />
          </Link>
          <h1 className="details__title">{listProduct.title}</h1>
          <div className="details__align--desk">
            <div className="details__img">
              <img
                className="product__img"
                src={listProduct.image}
                alt="Affichage du produit"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="products__align--desk">
              <h2 className="product__title">Description</h2>
              <p className="product__description">{listProduct.description}</p>
              <h2 className="product__title">Price</h2>
              <form className="form__price" onSubmit={this.submitHandler}>
                <input
                name="price"
                  className="input__price"
                  type="text"
                  defaultValue={Number(listProduct.price).toFixed(2)}
                  onChange={this.updatePrice}
                />
                <p>
                  Price (including VAT):{" "}
                  {Number(listProduct.price * 1.2).toFixed(2)} €
                </p>
                <br />
                <input
                  className="btn__update"
                  type="submit"
                  value="Update product"
                />
              </form>
            </div>
            <div className="category__align--desk">
              <h2 className="product__title">Category</h2>
              <p className={`${listProduct.category==="men's clothing" ? "category__orange" : "category__green"} product__category`}>{listProduct.category}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
```

I thank you in advance for your explanations

Comment: It's hard to say for certain but I don't see anywhere in your code where you're actually awaiting this API response which I believe is leading to a race condition on the rendering of your component and the return of the response. Just taking a bit of a guess though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem is that everything is working the API data has been retrieved, I can modify the price of the products, etc, but when I am on the product page and I refresh it gives me this error

Comment: Yes, I believe this is because when you refresh outside of that route the data has time to load and then you click onto that route and load that page. However if you're on that route directly and are trying to render a piece of data from that response like the title, you don't have that data yet.

You could just check `if (!products) return null` in your `ProdutDetails` component below where you destructure it. However, as @David has suggested in a below answer you can handle this with varying component states.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helps me a lot!

Comment: Sorry but i have to place the `if (!products) return null` where exactly? I don't see where i should put it (sorry i'm starting)

Comment: You're doing what's called destructuring here: `const { match: { params: { id } }, products } = this.props;`. You can check if you have products or not below this destructuring to create some loading states etc... using something like `if (!products) return null` is a pretty basic but useable solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect its because you're not covering a state when `listProduct` is `null`. When it loads, it immediately renders, as it's getting your product data, so `products` can be empty, and the `.find()` would return a `null`, then you're trying to render `listProduct.title` while it's `null`. Ideally, your render should check for `listProduct` being available or not.

Even better, have a few states of your component, like loading data, showing data, no data.

```
  <Card>
    { dataStatus === "Loaded" &&
      <Card.Title>{person.Name}</Card.Title>
    }
    { dataStatus === "Loading" &&
      <Card.Loader>Loading...</Card.Loader>
    }
    { dataStatus === "Error" &&
      <Card.Error>Sorry, we had an oopsie...</Card.Error>
    }
    { dataStatus === "Empty" &&
      <Card.Empty>Looks like we're missing something...</Card.Empty>
    }
  </Card>
```

Further explanation and code examples here: https://davidlozzi.com/2021/05/14/keeping-react-components-state-top-of-mind/

Comment: Thank you very much!! So it is in App that I have to put loading, showing and no data states, where I have axios the data?

Comment: "it depends" given what I see above, your component itself should handle its own state, unless you have more components sharing the same data, then create an object to share the state across components. `ProductDetails` should have its own checks for data and handle when its not valid. I would add a new object for `dataStatus`, options could be `"Loading", "Loaded", "Error", "Empty"` and your component can respond to each one of those states.

Comment: _loved this so creating a blog post_ updated answer with example of using `dataStatus`